# Html5 video in-built next/previus chapter button

Tags: html, video

i already made my research in the google but i
haven't found that if it is possible to use in-built
 next/previuse chapter(or track) like it was in some swf video.

I found this 
[Chapter Markers](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/08/building-interactive-html5-videos/)

But in my case it would be better if i can have the next/previous buttons next to the play button.Is this supported by basic html5 video player or should i use specific?

Comment: no native support. you would have to skin the player yourself and add UI and set the playhead to the right place when selected